# How to retrieve a list of another function in a list of the current function?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I am developing a script that allows to retrieve JSON data.
I have a first function, which will retrieve the JSON and return it in the format of a list (JSONArray).

Here this function :

```
def search_obs(cid):
# Call the API
response = api_i.get_case_obs(caseId, query={}, sort=['-stte', '+ioc'], range='all')

if response.status_code == 200 or response.status_code == 201:
    # Get response data
    list = json.dumps(response.json())
    return list
else:
    print('Failure: {}/{}'.format(response.status_code, response.text))
```

Then, a second function will retrieve the list, but it must retrieve it as a list and not as an str:

```
def create_cts(nwd, idd):

  obs = search_obs(idd)

  # we check that the obs are not empty
  if obs != "[]":

    obj_python = json.loads(json_data)
      
    for item in observables:
        str_item = str(item)
        str_dbquote = str_item.replace("'",'"')
        obj_python = json.loads(str_dbquote)
```

The problem is that I'm retrieving the list here with the "obs" variable, so it's not a list anymore. I need to fetch as a list because otherwise I couldn't iterate through the JSON which contains multiple objects.

Here is an example of JSON:

```
[
 {"_id": "~81940632", 
  "id": "~81940632", 
  "createdBy": "xxxx", 
  "createdAt": 1672847636169, 
  "_type": "case_artifact", 
  "dataType": "ip", 
  "data": "xxxx", 
  "startDate": 1672847636169, 
  "tlp": 2, 
  "tags": ["ip"], 
  "ioc": false, 
  "sighted": false, 
  "message": "nonne", 
  "reports": {}, 
  "stats": {}, 
  "ignoreSimilarity": false}, 
 {
  "_id": "~196840", 
  "id": "~196840", 
  "createdBy": "xxxx", 
  "updatedBy": "xxxxx", 
  "createdAt": 1672741863059, 
  "updatedAt": 1672843716872, 
  "_type": "case_artifact", 
  "dataType": "domain", 
  "data": "***@***", 
  "startDate": 1672741863059, 
  "tlp": 2, 
  "tags": ["domai"], 
  "ioc": true, 
  "sighted": false, 
  "message": "", 
  "reports": {}, 
  "stats": {}, 
  "ignoreSimilarity": false
 }
]
```

It is this data that is contained in the "list" variable and that I retrieve in "obs"

Comment: Why does `search_obs()` convert the list back into a string? Did you mean `return  response.json()`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wrote down my code incorrectly, I return `response.json()` directly. So in the `obs` variable I get the wanted list. The problem now is that in the JSON there are "False" values that it doesn't like when I do `json.loads()`

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. What is `create_cts()` trying to do? It gets `obs` as a list, but you don't use `obs` again in that function.

Answer (score 0):

If `obs` is a user defined variable, declare it as empty array. `obs = []` and then store the output of search_obs function.
Also in your code, we check that the obs are not empty

`if obs != "[]":`

Is your intention to check if obs not equal to empty list/array?? In that case do not use ""(double quotes) as it is read as string.